# Shopify cart/update.js not working with stock correclty

Tags: json, shopify

I'll try to keep it short. Basically I have a very simple "increase" button quantity on my website. Since users can add multiple identical variants to cart with different line item properties, I had to start using "item.key", which shows each variant with different line items as unique in cart. Now a simple JSON works fine for updating quantity in the cart (even with multiple same variants in cart):

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "quantity": qty,
    "id": itemkey,
    "sections": sectionsToRender,
    "sections_url": sections_url
  });
```

However problem occurs when there is not enough stock. For example you have 2 identical variants with different properties added in cart. A total of 3 added to the cart, while stock is 3 as well. You try to add the 4th, it returns 422, yet it still updates the item you tried to increase, while removing the other one who shares the same variant id, yet is completely different item.key.

I can't wrap my head around this, it should only affect the one that has item.key you're updating, not the other one.

I tried using "line" as well (instead of item.key), as suggested by Shopify but there seems to be identical problem. Again to make it clear, it works fine as long as there is enough stock and user is not exceeding the stock amount.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by first getting inventory into the JS. When in the process of allowing the customer to change a quantity, I block the call to update quantity at Shopify if they are going to exceed inventory. That makes this issue you have not happen.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Yes, I was thinking of going that way. However, that would require showing an actual stock, which is not really ideal... Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Comment: You don't have to show it. Besides there being few secrets in Shopify front-end, but yes, sure. If you want to pretend inventory is sacred like that, then you're up against a tough nut to crack!

Comment: Lol yeah, I agree, just me being me I guess. But I've seen some website get it to work without stock (pura vida bracelets), so showing stock would be the last resort.